# When is useEffect called in React Native for app that may run in background

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, background-process

Suppose I have a React Native App that has useEffect as follows:

```
export default function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        SOME CODE HERE
        console.log("useEffect initialization code called");
        return () => do_cleanup();
    }, [])

    function do_cleanup() {
        SOME CODE HERE
        console.log("useEffect cleanup code called");
    }
```

My understanding is that by using useEffect with the empty dependencies argument [], the code in useEffect runs only once after initial rendering, so console.log will only print "useEffect initialization code called" once as the app is being used.

I don't understand a couple of things though:

1. When is the do_cleanup function called? The docs say that this is called when the component unmounts, but what exactly has to happen for the entire App to unmount?
2. Suppose my app also has location services updating device location and it operates when the app is in a background state. When the app transitions from foreground to background state, does that result in do_cleanup being called. In other words, is that a condition where App would "unmount"?
   And if the App is then moved back into the active state, does it "mount" again, so that the useEffect code is called again?

Is there any way in useEffect to determine that the app is just going from a background to active state, or active to background state? I have some code that needs to ONLY run when the app is first launched and some cleanup code that should only run when the app closes. In other words, it should not run when the app just changes state from foreground to background. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use AppState Api for listening AppState changes

```
useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", nextAppState => {
      if (
        appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
        nextAppState === "active"
      ) {
        console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
      }

      appState.current = nextAppState;
      setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
      console.log("AppState", appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

more ref from [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate)